# No Post matches the given query. django blog

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

everything is ok in the model but when I try to retrieve the object the error "No Post matches the given query." is shown.
I don't know what is the problem that shows this error?

```
**Model**
class Post(CoreField):
    ....
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.month,
                             self.publish.day,
                             self.slug])

**url**
path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),

**views**
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    single_post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                                    publish__year=year,
                                    publish__month=month,
                                    publish__day=day,
                                    slug=post
                                    )
    # List of active comments for this post
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    # Form for users to comment
    form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'news/post_detail.html', {'post': single_post, 'comments': comments, 'form': form})
```

when I remove the remove the "int:year/int:month/int:day/" form url it works.
but when I pass the "int:year/int:month/int:day/slug:post/" it does't work.

What is the proble and where it happens????

Comment: Its the exception raised by [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) when it does not find any objects.

Comment: @FaridNaimi: this simply means that there is no `Post` for the given year, month, day, and slug combination.

Comment: The **Post** is in the database with the publish datetime and slug but only it does not display in the template.

Answer (score 0):

In your post_detail view, I think you should pass "slug" as an argument to the view instead of "post" because post is not a model field nor is it defined anywhere. And the "slug=post" kwarg should probably be reversed to avoid further errors.
So the post_detail view should probably look like this:

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
    single_post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                                    publish__year=year,
                                    publish__month=month,
                                    publish__day=day,
                                    post=slug
                                    )
```